# Keystroke file not Found. #Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

*macOS

I have generated my keystroke file as name: 'key.jks'

**when i run:**
`flutter build apk`

**error:**

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.

> Keystore file '/key.jks>' not found for signing config 'release'. `

**my 'key.jks' file location:**
`...android/app/key.jks`

**my 'key.properties'**

```
storePassword=123456
keyPassword=123456
keyAlias=key
storeFile=/key.jks>
```

**my 'key.properties' location:**
`...android/key.properties`

**my 'build.gradle' location:**
`android/app/build.gradle`

Comment: hi, interesting, is there a stray `>` in the file path.

Comment: yes @IronMan, `storeFile=/key.jks>` , '>' it was there by default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `key.properties` we should set the correct `storeFile`:

```
storePassword=
keyPassword=
keyAlias=key
storeFile=./key.jks
```

You probably left an extra `>` at the end, by following the [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android):

```
storePassword=<password from previous step>
keyPassword=<password from previous step>
keyAlias=key
storeFile=<location of the key store file, such as /Users/<user name>/key.jks>
```

---

Remember to keep the `key.properties` file private and don't check it into public source control for security reasons.

Comment: Thank you!
this worked for me `storeFile=./key.jks` instead od `storeFile=/key.jks>`